# Go parsing time string

Tags: go

I currently have the following date string

```
May 21 2016, 21:47:08 CEST
```

So I want to parse it. I tried the following

```
time, err := time.Parse("Jan 2 2006, 15:04:05 MST", date)
```

But I am getting the following error

```
parsing time "May 21 2016, 21:47:08 CEST" as "Jan 2 2006, 15:04:05 CEST": cannot parse " 21 2016, 21:47:08 CEST" as " "
```

I think I have checked that all the values are correct on the layout.

Comment: You probably missed a space in the beginning or something. I took the value and wrote a playground program and it just works. https://play.golang.org/p/ka3btmI4W0

Comment: I tried your example and please take a lookt at this. No idea why my string wont work https://play.golang.org/p/EtuohgMP8R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compare the two strings (the one that won't work, and where you type the "same" string in manually) and you can see there's a difference. The string that doesn't work uses **A0** (hex) *non-breaking space*, while the one that works uses the regular *space* **20** (hex).

You can see it in the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/6UIEKg9hs0